# Problems to install couponic on localhost

Tags: yii

I'm trying to install the couponic on my localhost (xampp), but I'm getting an error message:

Strict Standards: Non-static method UFactory::getModuleAlias() should not be called         statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in    C:\xampp\htdocs\couponic\framework\uniprogy\framework\worklets\UWorkletConstructor.php on line 254

This is one of the errors, but all of them are from the same type on the same function (getModuleAlias).

I already rename the protected/config/inital folder to protected/config/public and when I access using the url right url (localhost/couponic/install) I get these errors.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable strict errors in your php.ini:
error_reporting = E_ALL

Right now you probably have:
E_ALL & E_STRICT

So you need to lose the E_STRICT part.

Comment: I'm getting the same error; just a wall of this Non-Static method stuff...I tried turning off strict errors, but I still get the same result...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have install probably in  localhost php 5.4 and couponic doesn't support php 5.4, to bypass this problem you will have to replace

```
public function getModuleAlias($module)
```

with

```
static public function getModuleAlias($module)
```

but more problem will come up, until uniprogy make the script working on php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

I had "E_ALL" already and it wasn't working. I switched to "E_ERROR" and that did the trick.

`error_reporting = E_ERROR`

E_ALL "includes E_STRICT as of PHP 6.0.0" but we're not quite there yet.

Comment: Ha, "as of PHP 6.0.0"